# Carousel are crazy with click many times on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have make a carousel with jquery. The carousel have three sections and a large background images. When you click on the right button. The next section is coming and the background image is scrolling -1000 pixels to right.

But now the problem. When i click verry fast of a couple of times on the next button. The hole carousel is going crazy. How can i fix that? When you click on the next button. Then you can not print again. You must wait until he is animated. Thanks for help.

You can see the code on JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6RJzU/1/

Comment: I don't recommend smoking on a carousel...

Comment: The smoke is not the problem... When you click on the next button. You can click many times on it. When you click many times on this button. The carousel is going broken...

Comment: Before starting your new animation (going to the next/prev image) try testing if an animationis currently running. You can use: `$('%selector%').is(':animated')` and [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to do this.

Comment: I dont understand. Can you give me an example on jsFidle

Comment: Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/gKtEU/3/  when repeatedly clicking on on #foo, you'll see that the animation is only started when not allready running. (`if ($(this).is(':not(:animated)')) ...`). In your case you could do this on the `background` object in the button-click event handlers.

Comment: Thanks!!! I learn a lot from you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this fix it ??

http://jsfiddle.net/6RJzU/2/